# I want to finish the activity from an other activity on pressing the back button

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have an activity named `QRCodeReader` it has a back button on it. It scans the qr code and pass the id to `MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity` to start the channel. Its working fine. But when i press the back button of the `QrCodeReader` it finishes the current activity but it loads the blank arel camera web view of `MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity`. So i want to finish that the web view also. 
If i use the finish in onResume of MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity it works fine for back button of `QRCodeReader`. But i need that activity when i have to scan the code. I just want to finish it on pressing the back button in `QRCodeReader`.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you have to finish MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity on pressing back button in 
QRCodeReader Activity.

If my understanding is correct, then try this...

Declare a static handler in MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity

```
public static Handler h
```

and in my onCreate() method of MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity, implement this code

```
h = new Handler () 
     {
             public void handleMessage(Message message)  
              {
                super.handleMessage(message);
                 switch(message.what) 
               {
                 case 0:
                    finish();
                    break;
                 }
            }
      };
```

Now override onBackPressed in QRCodeReaderActivity & add call MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

like this..

```
//onBacKPressed of QRCodeReaderActivity ..
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

Comment: can u post the logerror on crash? I mean what exact the crash is?

Comment: it's java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity is on the stack when u pressed back in QRCodeReaderActivity ?

Comment: You will get nullPointerException if "Handler h" is not initialized, check out in this way... try to declare this static handler globally

Comment: it's global, Both of these activities are using camera so i think it is some sort of problem that both can't use the camera at same time

Comment: When i use the finish in the OnResume of MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity then it exists but in that way it does not work properly for the scanning the QR code and loading the data

Comment: Camera wont make problem.. In your methodloogy, I mean using finish() in OnResume. Before calling finish() in onResume, try to do something with that data you captured...

Comment: I need MetaioCloudARViewTestActivity when i am scanning because it's loads the data automatically after scanning so it's in the stack but if i press the back button it just shows the camera and finishes the QRCodeReaderActivity. I want to finish that camera view